# SWIG C/C++ python interface

Tags: python, c++, c, swig

I have the following C-file (ezrange.c):

```
double range(double *v1, int n1, double *v2, int n2)
{
  for (int i=0; i<n1; i++) {
    v1[i] = 1.0*i;
  }
  for (int i=0; i<n2; i++) {
    v2[i] = 2.0*i;
  }
  return 3.14;
}
```

with header (ezrange.h):

```
double range(double *v1, int n1, double *v2, int n2);
```

and SWIG interface file (ezrange.i):

```
%module ezrange

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "ezrange.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
    import_array();
%}

%apply (double* ARGOUT_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double* v1, int n1), (double* v2, int n2)}

%include "ezrange.h"
```

and setup file (setup.py):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# System imports
from distutils.core import *
from distutils      import sysconfig

# Third-party modules - we depend on numpy for everything
import numpy

# Obtain the numpy include directory.  This logic works across numpy versions.
try:
    numpy_include = numpy.get_include()
except AttributeError:
    numpy_include = numpy.get_numpy_include()

# ezrange extension module
_ezrange = Extension("_ezrange",
                   ["ezrange.i","ezrange.c"],
                   include_dirs = [numpy_include],
                   )

# ezrange setup
setup(  name        = "range function",
        description = "range takes an integer and returns an n element int array where each element is equal to its index",
        author      = "Egor Zindy",
        version     = "1.0",
        ext_modules = [_ezrange]
       )
```

I compile as follows:

swig -python ezrange.i

python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace

When I start python3 I get:

```
>>> import ezrange
>>> ezrange.range(3, 5)
[array([ 0.,  1.,  2.]), array([ 0.,  2.,  4.,  6.,  8.])]
>>>
```

I am missing the double return value (3.14). How can I get that value in python?

Thanks!

Comment: I built your code, but got `[3.14, array([ 0.,  1.,  2.]), array([ 0.,  2.,  4.,  6.,  8.])]` as the output.  That's as expected...the output arrays should be appended to the normal output value.

Comment: Which version of SWIG did you use?

Comment: I had a rather old 2.0.12 on my system.